# Custom Button popup modal not open

Tags: magento2, modal-popup

I need Quick Order button at product page like this website 
[Example Website](http://www.shophive.com/approved-used-logitech-ipad-pro-10-5-inch-keyboard-case-slim-combo-with-backlit-wireless-keyboard) 
I have created button at my website using attribute and the following code

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view

but button not open popup modal window like above example mention website

```
        <?php if($_product->getCustom_button()){ //yes or no button?>
    <button type="button"
                        title="<?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_name() ;?>"
                        class="action primary"
                        onclick="window.onload('<?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_url() ;?>')"><span><span><i class="icon-desktop"></i><?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_name() ;?></span></span></button>
    <?php } ?>
```

my product page test url is [URL Here](https://vistabazaar.com/lenses.html) 
and image [image]

Comment: check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

Comment: your javascript does not look right, are you trying to use window.open() instead of window.onload()?

Eg: window.open("https://www.w3schools.com","test",'width=600');